# How to intercept the marshmalling (json serial/deserial) from a CrudRepository declared as a @RepositoryRestResource?

Tags: json, serialization, spring-data, postgis, spring-data-jpa

Given this repository

```
@RepositoryRestResource( path = "u", itemResourceRel="ui", collectionResourceRel = "us")
public interface IUserRepository extends CrudRepository<Users, Long> {
}
```

When I go through a controller to call my service method `findAllUsers()`. I transform the 
list of entities result (returned by `userRepository.findAll()` method provided for free) to a list of domain model objects. This list of domain model objects will get properly deserialize into JSON because I am controlling how to do the deserialization. There is a specific reason why I am doing this, see further below.

Now, if I want to use the `userRepository` directly, I am running into a loop during the serialization because the object being deserialized are coming from the library `com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry`. This class contains a method as described below

```
  Geometry getEnvelope() Returns this Geometrys bounding box.
```

During the deserialization, jackson runs into a loop, because of it. I am able to correct the deserialization process within my controller. How could I intercept the deserialization from a `CrudRepository`?

The first idea that came to me was to create an implementation of my interface and override all methods, but it defeats the purpose of doing boiler-plate code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You show the usage of `@RepositoryRestResource` I am assuming you're using Spring Data REST to export your repositories. For standard Spring MVC marshaling configuration see the [reference docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-customize).

Precisely speaking, you're not intercepting the repositories. Spring Data REST uses Jackson to marshal and unmarshal the responses and requests. Hence you simply customize the Jackson `ObjectMapper` that SD REST will use. To do so, you extend `RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration` and override `configureJacksonObjectMapper(…)`:

```
class MyConfiguration extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration {

  protected void configureJacksonObjectMapper(ObjectMapper mapper) {
    // register custom serialializers, modules etc.
  }
}
```

For customization options in general, have a look at the Jackson [reference documentation](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/CategoryJackson).

Comment: Yes I am using Spring Data REST. When the Jackson marshall and unmarshall I am running into an infinite loop because of the object `com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry` that has the method shown above. This method returns another `com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry` hence the loop when un/marshmalling. This is why I need to customize this process.